# Linking data in a Microservices architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices, soa

I have a website and two Java microservices (user service, reports service)

On the website I am trying to tie up reports to users. However both of these services are unaware of the entities they are related to.

So my plan is to create a linking table in the website. Which allows it to query data from both services and then display it in a meaningful way.

My question is essentially, should I add extra properties to those services e.g. `user_id` to reports service. So that each service is aware of the other service.

Or use the website (PHP / MySQL) to persist the relationships between these two entities?

My only worry with using the website to persist all relationships, is that it could have scaling issues when I add more services. Also if that website goes down, the data is useless.

Is there any other ways to structure my data across these services.

Any suggestions welcome!

Note:- this is early stages, there are no other dependencies currently

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context on the domain? How are the reports created and how do they logically relate to the users?

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you add a unique identifier to relate both entities. so not only persisting the data it can be used for all the CRUD operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the other hand you can make use of PHP/MySQL as well. if you are going to use PHP then go with ORM (**Object-relational mapping**) framework. so you can handle the way how your entities will be saved, whether all child nodes or individual entities.